# i would like to send 500 Post request / Second with Nodejs any ideas

Tags: asynchronous, facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

i'm working on facebook chatbot so i hope to send message to All 1,7M users iterate one by one so i hope to send 500 Message / 1 Second ( 500 post request / second ) 
any ideas with nodeJs , async , anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at https://socket.io/, by making sure all your 1.7M are connected you need to implement more. SocketIO is purely async way of doing it.

Facebook chatbot already uses MQTT pattern.Take a look at that.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: but how to connect with facebook endpoint using socket io can u give me an example to end point /messages with data { id:"5" }, i'm already know socket io but i don't know how to deal with that in facebook

Comment: socket.io is for realtime communication, that´s a completely different use case

Answer (score 0):

Don´t try to send messages to each single user, use the `Broadcast API` instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/broadcast-messages/

Comment: i did it before but sometimes Message sent to All my 1,7M , sometimes 100K only there's variation everytime so i hope to use Send API , but in nodejs when i make for loop with inside post request to Send APi so i have 1,7M iterations with 1,7M post request , i'm using setInterval to send every 2ms i think it should sent to all within 1H but it takes 6H from me